# Best dilution in Rodinal for developing Tri-X at Box Speed

Tags: film, development, rodinal

I only have Rodinal at hand. And I'm using Kodak Tri-X 400 shot at Box Speed.

What's the recommended dilution for Rodinal? 1:50 or 1:100 or others.

Stand development or following Mass Dev chart?

Comment: "best" is also entirely relative. What you like may be an awful look to another

Comment: The difference in the final look depending on the Rodinal dilution is minimal, but I have to second timvrhn here. IMHO, your 'best' option is to either use a different film *or* a different developer. Developing Tri-X in Rodinal will give you very course grain.

Comment: What were the lighting conditions?

Comment: @Hueco outdoor, cloudy with yellow filter.

Answer (score 2):

There's no useful definition of 'best'.  For a long time I used 1+25, now I used 1+50, both using pretty much the massive dev chart's times (and I always use it at 400).  1+25 is possibly a little grainier, but both look fine enlarged to 12x16, assuming what you want is something that looks like a print from 35mm Tri-X.